# running command on remote machine with tramp?

Tags: emacs, command, tramp

I opened a file on the remote machine, and typed `C-u M-!` and then typed `tree` command. It showed in the buffer:

```
/bin/sh: tree: command not found
```

The `tree` command is installed into `/home/RNAer/bin`, and I verified it can run successfully when login with bash terminal.

Then I added the path in the `.emacs` like the following and restart emacs,

```
(add-to-list 'tramp-remote-path "/home/RNAer/bin")
```

but it still has the same error of command not found. what's the problem?

Comment: Where did you add `/home/RNAer/bin` to `$PATH` on the remote machine?  In other words, is this directory also added to `$PATH` in **non-interactive** shell sessions?

Comment: It is added to `~/.bashrc` (which is sourced by `~/.bash_profile`), in the interactive shell. But I tested it - even if I add to the $PATH in non-interactive shell session, it still failed.

Comment: Did you remove your persistency file? (By default the persistency file is `~/.emacs.d/tramp`)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I solved by adding the following lines to .emacs

```
(require 'tramp) 
(add-to-list 'tramp-remote-path "/home/RNAer/bin")
```

Note that without first line the second line throws error. You could double check your tramp-remote-path by

```
(message (format "%s" tramp-remote-path))
```

to see if your path is set correctly.